# indices do not match while training Sequential model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I followed all the code as I found on this site:

https://appliedmachinelearning.blog/2019/10/31/event-vs-non-event-classification-in-financial-documents-text-classification/

But getting an error at this line:

```
model.fit(train_X, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32)

InvalidArgumentError:  indices[12,78] = 4291 is not in [0, 4000)
     [[node embedding_1/embedding_lookup (defined at /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_1942]

Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph
```

The full code is available here:

https://github.com/shantanuo/stack_question/blob/master/nlp.ipynb

Comment: !wget https://datameetgeobk.s3.amazonaws.com/datagiri/30_companies_filings_event_nonevent_final_data.xlsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty self explanatory:

The embedding is trying to find the value 4291, but you have only 4000 tokens in your embedding.

So, the problem is either:

- `train_X` should not have a value >= 4000; or
- the embedding should have been created with enough tokens: `input_dim  = train_X.max() + 1`.

How you are going to treat this depends a lot on how you are preprocessing your data. If you are discarding rare words or replacing them with some "rare_word" token, or whether you are going to make the embedding have all words in the training set, etc.